# What is the input of little o notation?

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

In
$$\sin x=x+o\left(x^{2}\right)$$

can i write $o\left(x\right)$ instead of $o\left(x^{2}\right)$,
because i understand that little o means strictly less, and after the first term $x$ of $sin  x$ in taylor expansion there is $-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$ and $-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$ is strictly less than $x^{2}$, but also  $-\frac{x^{3}}{3!}$ is strictly less then $x$ so can i put $o\left(x\right)$ instead of $o\left(x^{2}\right)$?

Comment: Any $f(x)$ which is $o(x^2)$ as $x\to 0$ is also $o(x)$ since $|x^2| < |x|$ when $|x|<1$.  But an $f(x)$ which is $o(x^2)$ as $x\to \infty$ is not necessarily $o(x)$: take $f(x)=x$ as an counter-example.

Comment: thanks Henry it really did help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that $f$ is $\text{o}(g(x))$ as $x \to x_0$ if $f(x)=g(x)\omega(x)$ with $\omega(x) \to 0$ as $x \to x_0$.

So you have $\text{o}(x^2)=x^2 \omega(x)=x\cdot x\omega(x)$ as $x\to0$, letting $\omega_1(x):=x\omega(x)$ it is $\omega_1(x) \to 0$ as $x \to 0$; hence $\text{o}(x^2)$ is $\text{o}(x)$ as $x\to0$.

I suggest you to understand the definition of o, so you don't have to rely much on intuitive reasoning like "strictly less" that can lead you to make mistakes.

Comment: Thanks man, i'll try to understand the formal definition (since it's bit hard :p) but i use the strictly less analogy to make sense of it, i'm curious tho why not use the analogy, did you encounter some case where it failed?